# Inspect edge on Remote devices result in 404 not found

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug an app on Edge for Android (chromium based)
My desktop Chrome discovered the device and show the tab but when I click on "inspect" it result in a 404 not found

[image]

Comment: Looks like https://crbug.com/853525